# Changing the color of a child class inside a certain parent class

Tags: css

I want to change the color of class `number3` for websites that have the class `category` as one of its parents. The only way I know to change the color would be:

```
.category > .number1 > .number2 > .number3 {color:purple;}
```

But I guess there is a better solution without naming every parent class of `number3`.

How can I change the color from green to purple using CSS without knowing the names of the parent classes, where one of them is class `category`?

```css
.number1 {color:blue;}
.number2 {color:red;}
.number3 {color:green;}
.category {color:yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="category">
        Text1
  <div class="number1">
  Text2
  <div class="number2">
    Text3
    <div class="number3">
      Text4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply name the parent and then the element you want to style

```
.category .number3 {color:purple;}
```